# Metadata Compare- is there an easier way than selecting all components in eclipse, then using a tool like Kaleidescope(mac)

Tags: metadata, migration-tool, migration

I'm in progress with a Metadata Compare of 2 Salesforce Sandboxes. As part of a client requirement, we have to do a full compare that migration to a new sandbox is complete. We are using changesets, it's a large org with over 500 custom objects.

For Sandbox1 - I create a new force.com project in Eclipse, selected all components, then waited (about 15 mins), then went export, and exported as a Zip file including folder structure.

For Sandbox2 - I did the exact same.

Now I'm using [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/) for Mac to compare them.

Is there an easier to do the above, eg. Use the package contents of Sandbox1 as a template for Sandbox2 so I don't have to select all again? Or are there better tools for Mac to do a full org metadata compare?

Comment: There are tools like “SnapShot” by “Dream Factory” http://www.dreamfactory.com/force.com/snapshot. Also, (have not used Force.com IDE for eclipse for years, so can not be 100% sure) but I think eclipse project respects package.xml. So if you take package.xml from your Sandbox1 eclipse project and copy it to Sandbox2 project (may be better to have Eclipse closed for this) and then (in Eclipse) refresh Sandbox2 project, then (in theory) this shall spare you from having to select all components in Sandbox2 project manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [SF org compare](https://sforgcompare.herokuapp.com)

Should be easier than retrieving all the metadata & comparing locally.

Answer (score -1):

We have apps like [AutoRABIT](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000ptkwEAA)  in appexchange

Which does Metadata compare ,automatic deployments etc.. The following are the some screenshots from this app. This is available in both limited free usage and licensed also.

[image]

[image]
Thanks,

Naveen